# Unnesting structs in BigQuery to flatten

Tags: struct, google-bigquery, flatten

How I can, to get a flat table structure with a prefix to columns or with the name of the main column?

table of the following structure

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 'Alex' AS name, 14 AS age, 'something else 1' other_field UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bert' AS name, 14 AS age, 'something else 2' other_field UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Chiara' AS name, 13 AS age, 'something else 3' other_field
),
struct_data AS(
    SELECT (
      SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT(other_field)
      FROM UNNEST([t])
      ) AS student_data,
      (
      SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT(other_field)
      FROM UNNEST([t])
      ) AS duble_data
    FROM data t
)
SELECT 
   student_data.*,
   duble_data.*
FROM struct_data
```

and if you use the operator. * then the name of the pillars will be duplicated

[image]

how can one write a query to get flat structure output?

```
Row student_data_name   student_data_age   duble_data_name   duble_data_age     
1   Alex                14                 Alex                14
2   Bert                14                 Bert                14
3   Chiara              13                 Chiara              13
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you are unnesting your source table, it isn't an array.
If you build your `struct` cte a little better, it is really simple.

Consider:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 'Alex' AS name, 14 AS age, 'something else 1' other_field UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bert' AS name, 14 AS age, 'something else 2' other_field UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Chiara' AS name, 13 AS age, 'something else 3' other_field
),
structed as (
    select
        struct(name,age) as student_data,
        struct(name,age) as duble_data
    from data
)
select * from structed
```

It isn't specifically what you asked for, but still provides a 'flattened' representation.  This can obviously change a bit depending on the complexities of your actual data.  I personally prefer the `struct.field` instead of `struct_field` format in my tables because it implies hierarchy... that field *belongs* to that struct.